# Kotlin safe call (?.) clarification?

Tags: kotlin

Per kotlin docs(https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kotlin-tour-null-safety.html#use-safe-calls)

> To safely access properties of an object that might contain a null value, use the safe call operator ?.. The safe call operator returns null if the object's property is null. This is useful if you want to avoid the presence of null values triggering errors in your code.

I have always thought that safe call returns null when the object is null because it doesn't really matter if the property is null or not. If a called property is null we could simply return this property as null.

Hopefully someone could clarify this part of kotlin doc.

Comment: Those aren't the right docs, that is the tour. [Here are the docs from the language reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#safe-calls) for that operator. Looks like the tour is written less precisely, which isn't that unusual.

Comment: `val obj = foo?.someProp` will assign `null` to `obj` if either `foo` or `someProp` is `null`. That documentation is unclear at best.

Comment: I don't really see a question here. What are you asking? What's unclear about this?

Comment: I agree that this sentence you quoted from the docs "The safe call operator returns null if the object's property is null" is inaccurate. If I had to rewrite it I would have put down "The safe call operator returns null if the expression to its left evaluates to null". Thoughts?

Comment: @Sweeper The documentation says "_The safe call operator returns null if the **object's property** is null._" But that's not accurate, or at least unclear. The safe-call operator will return null if the **object** is null, not if the object's property is null (although it's true that null will be returned if the object's property is null, that has nothing to do with the safe-call operator).

Comment: That quoted info is extremely vague at best, and at worst is just wrong depending on how you interpret it.